# Find longest common subsequence in limited space

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, dynamic-programming, strings

Given three strings $x$, $y$, and $z$ over an arbitrary finite alphabet, I need to determine their longest common subsequence (LCS).

**Example**: A longest common subsequence of `bandana`, `cabana`, and `magazine` is `aan`.

I'm trying to find an algorithm which uses $O(|x|\cdot |y| \cdot |z|)$ space where $|s|$ denotes the length of the string $s$.

Comment: https://onestopinterviewprep.blogspot.com/2014/03/longest-common-subsequence.html The above C# code works great for all test cases. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard dynamic programming algorithm for the LCS$(x,y)$ problem runs in time $O(|x|\cdot |y|)$. Simply speaking you fill out a $|x| \times |y|$ table $T$ using the recursion
$$T[i,j] =
\begin{cases}
0
& \mbox{ if }\ i = 0 \mbox{ or }  j = 0 \\
 T(i-1,j-1) +  1
& \mbox{ if } x_i = y_j \\
  \max\{T[i,j-1],T[i-1,j]\}
& \mbox{ if } x_i \ne y_j \\
\end{cases}.$$

A natural extension of this recursion leads to an algorithm that fills out an $|x|\times |y|\times |z|$ table and computes the LCS of three strings.

Notice that you can improve the required space even further (while keeping the asymptotic running time) using  [Hirschberg's extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirschberg%27s_algorithm).